# Runtime polymorphism in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

Why I am getting 4, when base class function fun(int) is private and 5 if its default?.

```
class one 
{
    int a;  
    private void fun(int a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }


    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        one y= new B();
        y.fun(4);
        //  B obj =new B(); 
        //  obj.fun(4);
    }   
}

class B extends one
{
   void fun(int a)
    {
        a = a+1;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Java specification, the chapter  **8.4.8. Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m
>   (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all of the
>   following are true:
>
> - m is a member of the direct superclass of C.
> - m is **public, protected, or declared with package access** in the same
>     package as C.
> - No method declared in C has a signature that is a subsignature
>     (§8.4.2) of the signature of m.
>     .....
>     .....
>     **8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)**
> - An instance method mC declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method mA declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>     .....
> - One of the following is true:
>
>   - mA is public.
>   - mA is protected.
>   - mA is declared with package access in the same package as C, .....

The above means, that you can't override a private method, and a class B actually doesn't override `fun`.
If you either remove `private` modifier or declare `fun` as public or protected, then the code returns 5, because the `fun` method becomes "overrideable".

Comment: But why is `one.fun()` called rather than `B.fun()`?

Comment: class one got reference of B, so why one.fun() is called, rather then of B or error runtime / compile time.